# Pass Today's Date as Parameter in Scheduled JasperReports Server Report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a JasperReports scheduled in Jasper which takes the FromDate and ToDate where FromDate is fixed and I need to pass Today's date as ToDate in Integer format.

Report is running fine when I run manually on JasperReports Server and it is taking today's date as ToDate parameter. Below is the query for parameter which I have written in Jasper while creating parameter:

```
SELECT date_format( now(), '%Y%m%d') AS today
```

But when I schedule the report it seems ToDate input control is not passing the Today's date and I always get the date when I scheduled the report as ToDate.

I found few links for the similar issue but still I could not fix, need your help.

[Dynamic Date Parameters for Scheduler in JasperServer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/845770/dynamic-date-parameters-scheduler-jasperserver)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following could solve the problem:

```
SELECT date_format( now(), '%Y-%m-%d') AS today
```